# Define time in synthetic rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a rosbag from a csv file. I am using the python api. My question is how can I set the time information in the bag with which it will be player back. the relevant parts of my current code look like this:

```
import os
import rosbag
import rospy 
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
import numpy as np

try:
file = os.path.expanduser('test.csv')

# Get data from text file(s)
data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=',', skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, names=True)
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'w')
time = data['Nano_from_start_of_regions']
time = time - time[0]
v_x = data['Velocity_forwardms']
v_y = data['Velocity_lateralms']
v_z = data['Velocity_downms']
odom = Odometry()
time = np.array(time)
sec_time = time.astype(int)
nsec_time = (time-sec_time)*10e8
nsec_time = np.array(nsec_time)
nsec_time = nsec_time.astype(int)

for i in range(len(time)):
    odom.header.frame_id = 'odom'
    odom.child_frame_id = 'base_link'
    odom.header.stamp.secs = sec_time[i]
    odom.header.stamp.nsecs= nsec_time[i]
    odom.twist.twist.linear.x = v_x[i]
    odom.twist.twist.linear.y = v_y[i]
    odom.twist.twist.linear.z = v_z[i]

    bag.write('odom',odom)

finally:
bag.close()
```

how ever the time in the header doesnt seem to have an influence on the bag. its just saves it as fast as possible and replays at the same speed.
How could I change that speed? Clock topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290810/define-time-in-synthetic-rosbag/) by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a third parameter to write that holds the time, set it to header.stamp.

http://docs.ros.org/api/rosbag/html/python/

(I can't link straight to it because the html prevents it: click rosbag.bag on the left, then Bag on the right, then write() appears)

rosbag play will use that time during playback, it doesn't use the header time because many messages don't have headers.  Not supplying the time results in the current time being used.

The tutorial example should be changed to show that if it doesn't.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1